# Why is adding styling or widgets to Django forms will prevent data from being saved in database?

Tags: python, django

I just tried multiple ways of styling my Django form but every time I did it prevents data from being saved in Django's admin database.

Here is my code :

models.py :

```
class listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    describtion = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    bid = models.FloatField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(categories, default=1, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,default='', verbose_name="User", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} "
        
class create(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = listing
        fields = [ 'title', 'describtion','bid','category','image']
```

After adding widgets :

```
class create(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = listing
        fields = [ 'title', 'describtion','bid','category','image']
        widgets={
            'title': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'describtion': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'image': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'bid': NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'category': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Views.py:

```
def CreateListing(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = create(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = user
            form.save()
            return redirect('listing')
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/Create.html",{
        'form': create
    })
```

Ps : without widgets, data will be saved in the Database.

Comment: What about form.instance.save()? does it work?

Comment: no, in fact, I get a **The view auctions.views.CreateListing didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.** Error message.

Comment: Then your form is not valid as this the only path in your function that returns None.